# Replace number in notepad++

Tags: java, excel, notepad++, text-editor

I have numbers like `32,33,33.1,33.2,34,34.1,35,35.1,35.2,35.3,35.4,36` and so on. Now is it possible that if I will change the number 32 to 50, then all respective numbers will also change like `50,51,51.1,51.2,52,52.1,53,53.1,53.2,53.3,53.4,54` may be using regexp pattern or anything or coding in java.

Comment: You can't do operations in the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to code this in Java.  Arithmetic is impractical to do this with regexes.

Comment: You can do arithmetic operations in regex but not in an editor like Notepad++.

Comment: @M42 - Yes, you are correct.  But you either need to apply the regex multiple numbers of times, or you need a horribly complex regex.  It is not a *practical* proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Excel tag and assuming the numbers are in different cells, key `18` and copy that cell, select the numbers and Paste Special with Operation Add.